# php-Symfony2. Why I can not ship products from a page different than 1?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an issue trying to get the products from a page different of 1(there is a paginator).  If somebody can understand this code could be great, I'm new in symfony. I think it is due of this part of the code:

```
$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)
```

This is the controller.  It sends data data to page called getAll.html.twig.

```
/**
     * @Route("/get-all/{productRequestId}", name="userBuyerProductRequestGetAll", defaults={"productRequestId"=null} )
     * @Template()
     */
            public function getAllAction(Request $request, $productRequestId)
            {
                if ( !$this->getUser()->isAllowed("BUYER_PRODUCT_REQUEST")){
                    throw new AccessDeniedException();
                }

                if ( is_null($productRequestId) ) {
                    $productRequest = null;
                } else {
                    $productRequest = $this->getRepo()->find($productRequestId);
                }
                $company = $this->getUser()->getCompany();
                $criteria2 = $this->get('request')->query->get('criteria', "");
                $pagination2 = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
                $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("dsarhoyaSCBundle:Product")->getByCompanyAndCriteriaDQL($company->getId(),$criteria2    ),
                $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
                $this->get('request')->query->get('resultsCount', 20)/*results per page*/,
                array('defaultSortFieldName' => 'p.name', 'defaultSortDirection' => 'asc')
                );
                if ( !$this->getUser()->getCompany()->getProductRequestAccess() ){
                    return $this->redirectToRoute("userPurchaseBidIndex", array("companyId"=>$this->getUser()->getCompany()->getId()));
                }
                if ( !$this->getUser()->isAllowed("BUYER_PRODUCT_REQUEST")){
                    throw new AccessDeniedException();
                }
                $options = new ProductRequestOptions([
                    "criteria"=> $request->get("criteria",""),
                    "user"=>$this->getUser()
                ]);
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');
                $pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
                        $this->getRepo()->getByCompanyDQL($options),
                        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
                        $this->get('request')->query->get('resultsCount', 20)/*results per page*/,
                        array('defaultSortFieldName' => 'r.creationTime', 'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc')
                    );
                return array(
                    "criteria"=> $options->criteria,
                    "requests"=>$pagination,
                    "company"=>$company,
                    "products"=>$pagination2, 
                    "criteria"=>$criteria2, 
                    "step"=>1,
                    "productRequest"=>$productRequest
                    );
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass page variable in your URL.
Now, there'll always be a "1" value, it doesn't make sense.

Your route `/search-product/{productRequestId}` should include at least a page number.

As an element of your route:

```
/search-product/{productRequestId}/{page}
```

or as a get param:

```
/search-product/{productRequestId}/?page=number
```

where number is your page number.

Comment: It doesn't work with the two solutions.  The first I put page like extra element "public function getAllAction(Request $request, $productRequestId,$page)" but I didnt know where put the variable, the same with the second answer.

Comment: can you explain it better?

Comment: In the first case, you have to include it in a route params:

@Route("/search-product/{productRequestId}/{pageId}", name="userBuyerProductRequestSearchProduct", defaults={"productRequestId"=null} )

in a second one, 
$request->query->get('pageId');
will work.

are you sure that you pass params in a query string?

In your example:
$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1) 

you get 'page' param, or 1 when 'page' param is not available.

I guess it's not passed to the action.
So when you render a link to the next page, you have to do this like that:

{{ path('route', {'page': pageNumber }) }}

Comment: I did a dump of the variable ({{ dump('page') }}) 'page' and got 'page' without parameters  it's not passed to the action. I updated my question, I was wrong with the function header. I'm still getting nothing.

Comment: so you tried with url like this:
/search-product/{productRequestId}/?page=3
and $request->query->get('page') returns null?

Don't look into the view right now, you've got a problem inside a controller.

Comment: when I put "/get-all/{productRequestId}/?page=number" I get No route found for "GET /secured/buyer_user/product-request/get-all" (from "http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php/secured/buyer_user/product-request/get-all") I used the URL /product-request/get-all/?page=2 (productRequest can be null)

Comment: ok, it's because you don't have trailing slash. Router understand "/search-product/{productRequestId}", but not "/search-product/{productRequestId}/"
Try /search-product/{productRequestId}?page=number